# How find or add element by linq and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a function to find or add element in Entity Framework?

for example replace something like that:

```
public static Student findOrAdd(ModelSchool modelSchool,Student student)
{
    var newStudent = modelSchool.Students.Where(s => s.Name == student.Name).FirstOrDefault<Student>();

    if (newStudent == null)
    {
        newStudent = modelSchool.Students.Add(student);
    }

    return newStudent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You about have it. You can simply for LINQ statement as below. To make sure the new student is properly created, you need to call the `SaveChanges` method on your `DbContext` which I'm assuming your `ModelSchool` is.

```
public static Student findOrAdd(ModelSchool modelSchool,Student student)
{
    var newStudent = modelSchool.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == student.Name);
    if (newStudent == null)
    {
        newStudent = modelSchool.Students.Add(student);
        modelSchool.SaveChanges();
    }
    return newStudent;
}
```

Comment: I did it after I call the function instead, thats why I add the model as first parameter. 1 saveChanges. I was hopping for something integrated into entity6.